# ajax response over max value of range

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need help, please! I have a range input:

```
 <input type="range" name="set_workers" class="set_workers" id="set_workers" min="0" max="10">
  <input type="submit">
```

I have an ajax script run on page load getting some values. One of that values should be outputted over max range. So I want a range input with dynamic max value. Is there any way to do that? Should I echo a range in php to put it on ajax response?
here is my ajax:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var current_building = $('#building_name').val();
    $.ajax(
    {type: 'post',
    url: '../account_handle/get_cost_upgrade.php',
    data: {
    building: current_building,
},
    success: function (val){
   $('#display_cost').html(val.test1);
   $("#set_workers").attr("max", val.test2);
}
});

}
```

And the php code:

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM $buildcost WHERE lvl = '$lvl'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$max_w = $row['max_w'];

   echo json_encode(array(
"test1" => "doesn t matter",

"test2" => 
"$max_w"
  ));
```

I cutted some useless parts from php, php is not a problem, is working, same json, but i don t know how to put that value into max of range.
Thanks all!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "One of that values should be outputted over max range" ? Are you talking about the data returned from the ajax call? you can probably alter the max attribute when the ajax call returns so that it is some size related to the response data

Comment: yes, i mean php will echo a value that should be the max=".." (atribute) of the range

Comment: in your ajax success function you can do something like `$("#workers").attr("max", val[1]);` since that data is returned on the POST to get_cost_upgrade, you don't need to echo it since you are returning that data on the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should absolutely retrieve that maximum range value via an `echo` from php, and then pass that value into the the input's max attribute.  Something like this will do the trick.

```
    window.onload = function() {
        var current_building = $('#building_name').val();
        $.ajax(
        {type: 'post',
        url: '../account_handle/get_cost_upgrade.php',
        data: {
        building: current_building,
    },
        success: function (response){
       $('#display_cost').html(response); 
       //This line will set the "max" attribute to whatever you respond with in your PHP, 
       //although please note how you access that data depends on how you 
       //format it in your PHP

       $("#workers").attr("max", response.max)
       //Access the JSON object's value via it's key, like below
       console.log(response.test1);
       //or
       console.log(response.test2);



    }
    });

    }
```

**However**- You will need to modify your response in such a way to where you can access it in your ajax success function.  How you access it will vary on how you format the PHP response.  Happy to help with that if you post your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for kindness, sir ! I edited my post...forgot about php. Last row in php and in ajax are relative....i mean i don t know what to instead of...

Comment: @BoteaFlorin, you should now be able to access value of PHP json object via it's key.  I'll update my code to reflect that for  you.

Comment: @BoteaFlorin Please see my updates and let me know if it helps.

Comment: cool! Solved it! Thanks for help and sorry for wasting your time !

Comment: @BoteaFlorin it was not a waste of time, I'm very happy to help.  Please upvote my answer and mark my answer as the answer, it helps tremendously.